# Windows restores old home directory on each login

Tags: windows-7, windows, sync, home-directory

My main desktop is a Windows 7 Enterprise machine which is bound to a corporate Windows domain. My official user account is stored in the corporate domain / active directory. I can use any computer in the company to log in. When I log in, Windows copies my home directory from our central server to the workstation. When I log out, Windows copies my home directory from the workstation back to our central server.

I don't know why they don't simply mount the user directories. But that's not the point here. The point is that I recently have created a local user account on one of my workstations. This local account does not exist in the corporate active directory. But for some reason, Windows still syncs my new home directory on log in / log out. And I'm wondering how this is possible.

Where are my files synced to? I have already checked the file server. But my new home directory doesn't seem to be there.

Also, the sync is totally messed up. Instead of "updating the deltas", it always restores my old home directory. So, I basically can't log out anymore. Or, on the next login, my old home directory will be back with all my new files vanished and all changes reversed.

So, my question is: Which Windows mechanism could be responsible for this? Where should I look first?

Comment: Same user / username for a remote and local account? Could that be the problem?

Comment: The user/login names are different. The real/full names originally have been the same when I created the new account. But then I've changed my real/full name. So, all names are different now.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: @DavidPostill It may or may not be a corporate issue. So your comment is pointless.

Comment: It's not pointless. It's on a corporate network. If you **read** the link I gave you it is explicit: "and it is not about … issues specific to corporate IT support and networks". If you were **not** on a corporate network you wouldn't have the problem.

Comment: If you don't agree with the [SU] policies (defined by our community) the place to discuss it is [meta] not in comments. Please spend some time reading the [help] pages.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have already solved the problem. And it didn't have anything to do with our specify corporate IT.

Comment: Then feel free to [Answer Your Own Question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to change my profile type to "local profile".

Start > "Erweiterte Benutzerprofileigenschaften konfigurieren"

(= "Configure advanced user profile properties" (rough translation))

Answer (score -1):

Does it do it when you're not connected to the network? If so it's copying it locally. The only thing that I could thing of that could be causing this is a corrupt profile. Check out this article

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947215

Comment: Why has this answer been down voted? It actually led me on the right track.

Comment: @Lugaxx Because it doesn't actually answer you question. It is asking for more information, so it should be a comment.